# с++ define чем заменить в Java

Tags: java, c++, c

народ вот в С++ есть define а что в джаве чем заменит ?

хотел перевести код на java

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #define nmax 100
    void main()
    {
    int a[nmax][nmax];
    int i,j,n;
    int imax=0, jmax=0,imin=0,jmin=0;
    int max, min;
    int s=0;
   clrscr();
    printf("n manin engiz->");
scanf("%d",&n);
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
for (j=0;j<n;j++){
printf("a[%d][%d]=",i,j);
scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
}
}
max=a[0][0];
min=a[0][0];
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
for (j=0;j<n;j++){
if (a[i][j]<min){
min=a[i][j];
imin=i;
jmin=j;
break;
}
}
}
printf("\nOndelgen massiv \n");
printf(" min = %d\n",min);
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
for (j=0;j<n;j++){
printf("a[%d][%d]=%d ",i,j,a[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}
for (j=0;j<n;j++){
s=s+a[imin][j];
}
printf("S=%d",s);
getch();
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам макроопределение в Java?

Comment: если бы вы привели пример работы и описали его, люди знающие java но не знающие c++ могли бы так же помочь вам

Comment: @Виктор извиняюсь исправил

Comment: 1. отформатируйте код. 2. опишите словами, что вы делаете т.е. переменные imax. imin. jmax. jmin. min. max мало что говорят о ваших действиях. 3. Опишите что вы хотите поменять, как это работает и что делает в с++. Тогда люди знающие java смогут примерно вам подсказать.

Comment: ...`const` используйте, но джава и обычную переменную скушает.

Answer (score 3):

Зря минусуете, коллеги. А между прочим вопрос крайне интересный и важный. Если перевести на нормальный прогерский язык, то вопрос должен звучать как:

> есть ли в Java возможность использования возможностей препроцессинга?

Для тех, кто в танке (пардон не в курсе про C/C++) - в С/С++ есть такая штука - препроцессор, который до первого прохода компилятора, проводит некую предварительную обработку исходного текста, самая примитивная директива `#DEFINE` по сути инструкция замены текста другим текстом, есть и более продвинутые `#IFNDEF/ELSE` и проч.

Теперь ближе к делу.

1) В стандартной коробочной версии Java нет понятия препроцессинга

2) Но есть сторонние разработки, которые реализуют таковую возможность, [например эта](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor), код будет приблизительно такой:

```
//#ifndef VAR
System.out.println("VAR not defined!");
//#else
System.out.println("VAR defined!");
//#endif
```

Comment: а это где такое полезно бывает в джаве?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону `javac` (Если что, то это не язык). Есть возможность на разных стадиях сделать аналог `#define`. Точнее на стадии, где парсятся аннотации.